# How Do I Create a Variable In Z80 Assembly?

Tags: variables, assembly, z80, gameboy

I'm trying to create a simple variable containing the hex value `0xffff`. I've been able to do it as a macro with `SET`, but I haven't been able to get it working with something like `ld _time,$ffff`. How do I load a value into `_time`?

Comment: When you ask questions about assembly language programming you should specify which assembler you're using, because they differ in syntax. I'm going to guess that you're using RGBAsm. Note that `_time SET $ff` isn't really declaring a variable in the traditional sense - you're telling the assembler to replace all occurrences of `_time` with `$ff`. For a variable declaration you would use something like `DB`/`DW`/`DS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was I wasn't initializing `_time`. The following worked:

```
_time SET $ff
ld hl, $ffff
ld (_time),hl
```